# How do I add more locations for weather updates in Google Now?

Tags: google-now, geolocation, weather

Currently, Google Now shows me weather updates of my home and work locations. However, I want to add more locations for weather updates. But I couldn't find any setting regarding the same? Is it possible to add locations which are not your home or work? If yes how?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, however Google Now will automatically pop in weather cards for the locations where you are traveling (based on mails in your inbox).